# Antonym to "news"

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

I have very old info.  Is there a concise term like "news" that I can use to describe this?

Update:
I am looking for the antonym for *news*. Can I say *oldies*?

Comment: "Queen Anne's dead!"

Comment: ["Queen Anne's dead!"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/) FTFY @Brian.

Comment: FTFY? I was hoping we'd avoid such acronyms of laziness on an English Language site. :(

Comment: @RegDwight,  I cannot find what FTFY stands for except "First-Time First-Year", "full-time full-year". What did you mean?

Comment: "Fixed that for you." @Noldorin: that's not an acronym of laziness, that's an acronym to mimic a certain style.

Comment: Can you refer me where it is written how to make links in comments?

Comment: @RegDwight: Oh, I wasn't too serious. Just worth noting that many people aren't familiar with such acronyms. Thanks for explaining though!

Comment: @vgw8: It's normal Markdown syntax; same as in questions/answers.

Comment: @vgv8: `[link text](URL)`, see ["How do comments work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: @RegDwight, thanks a lot. @Noldorin, I've heard the word "markdown" for the first time in my life from you. I only knew "markup" untill now

Comment: propaganda, disinformation, misinformation, Fox "News"

Comment: Please add "Fars News" and "Press TV's News". On the other word "rumor".

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: The opposite of news is history

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The antonym of *news* is *history*. Depending on the context, that would be the word you want to use.

As alternative, you can use *old news*, or *stale news*.

Comment: Can I tell "new olds" also?

Comment: _Old_ is an adjective, differently from _news_ that is a _noun_. You cannot say _new olds_ because there isn't the plural of adjectives. _News_ is a noun, in Modern English as spoken nowadays.

Comment: It dpes not seem to be symmetric

Comment: Well, you *can* say "olds", but then most people will think it's wrong.  I do recall having seen "olds" somewhere, somewhen.  Just don't recall exactly where.

Comment: _Elders_ is an English word, but it is not correct to use it in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't say that history is a direct antonym - the most common term is old news.

Comment: *New olds* is the antonym of *your father's Oldsmobile*.

Comment: @jae. The word *olds* is used in the Terry Pratchett novel *The Truth*, but in the sense of boring news that's the same every day and reinforces people's existing beliefs. People don't really want *news* in a newspaper. They want *olds*. (Hence the *Daily Mail*.)

Comment: @TRIG: Pratchett's use of words is hardly canon :) He uses *olds* precisely because the fact that it is a conceivable but not actual usage of the word makes it hilarious. In the words of the man himself, "'Discworld' is taking something that you know is ridiculous and treating it as if it is serious, to see if something interesting happens when you do so." But if Pterry were more popular in the mainstream, his *olds* is actually a word people might start using.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably say something like 'old hat', but it does depend on the context.  'History' could be a better autonym.

Answer (score 0):

I often hear old media being described as "*from the vault*".  When referring to a news story you could say "And now something from the vault... [insert old news story here.]"

Answer (score 0):

I'd include "from the archive".

Answer (score 0):

News organizations store their prior output in *the morgue*.