# Is there a phrase to indicate the other party said something obvious

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My first language is Spanish. In Spanish, we have a phrase to indicate when someone has said something so obvious or basic that everyone knows and so there's no need to say it. Is kind of sarcasm. Not really offensive, but you are saying the other party has said a dumb thing.

> Felicitaciones, inventaste el agua tibia.
>
> Congratulations, you invented warm water.

The other day, I wanted to reply to a comment in a chat, but was not sure if that would have had the same impact/meaning in English as it has in Spanish.

**Aditional Info:**

In my case we were talking about an Android Game "Summoner Wars", where you collect monsters and runes, then equip the better runes to mosters to make them stronger.

You usually have to repeat same level multiple times, so as your monster get stronger you finish each level faster.

And the comment was: *"You need equip stronger runes to reduce your time".* and I was thinking *Yes, you just invented the warm water.*

Comment: @NVZ thanks for the edit. But I have a question. I wrote`in english as IS on spanish.` but you say should be `in english as IN on spanish.` doesnt make sense to me, could you elaborate why?

Comment: Sorry about that. English isn't my *main* language, either.

Comment: @NVZ That is ok,  That always gimme the chance to learn something new. BTW. I dont agree with the duplicate. Even when on of the answer is `No shit, Sherlock` and that make sense. The original question isnt similar to this one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Don't worry. If more people agree with you, this won't be closed. But the answers in the link might be useful, anyway. :)

Comment: Similar to the Spanish idiom is: "Yes, and water is wet"

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree that the linked question is a duplicate.

Comment: Gerald M Weinberg said, "No matter how strange it might look, most people are actually trying to be helpful."

Comment: Thanks @Marthaª , but also was my fault didnt include the example for start. But thanks every one for his comment.

Comment: It should be noted that the giving of such unhelpful advice is an invitation for trolling. The suggested answers communicate immediately that the statement was intuitively obvious, that's a missed opportunity I think. You should respond by wasting their time in equal measure to the amount of your time they have wasted. So ask something that you can ignore but they will put plenty of processing power into: "What combination of runes should I be striving for here?"

Comment: A better English translation of your Spanish phrase is:  "Congratulations, you invented warm water."  (no "the").  Sorry I can't explain in detail why.  You could say "invented the steam engine" (and it would be incorrect to omit "the" in that phrase).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes,  that make sense. Please forgive me that is just a habit from spanish, where you have to add the article `THE / EL` to refer anything.

Comment: No apology needed; happy to help you out.  As a native speaker, I'd like to apologize for the complexity of English, to everyone that has to learn it as a second language.  Sorry for taking over the world (or at least International communication in most fields).

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm working on it.... Geez, you ask some really hard questions!

Comment: @nocomprende Most importantly questions without an absolute answer. Meaning it is simply the carefully formulated opinion of the answerer, not something absolute or really all that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No shit, Sherlock

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=no%20shit%20sherlock

with *Sherlock* referring, of course, to Conan Doyle's famous consulting detective, Sherlock Holmes.

Sometimes people just say

> No kidding.

or

> Now tell me something I don't know.

There is nothing, that I'm aware of anyway, that closely resembles the translation you have provided.

Answer (score 24):

> Thank you, Captain Obvious.

I believe that calling someone Captain Obvious implies that they are a person who is adept at making obvious statements.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Obvious

Comment: This is something I'd understand as an American English speaker but I've never heard it used.

Comment: It's common enough currently that a company (hotels.com, though I wouldn't have remembered that offhand) has been running a TV ad campaign starring a "Captain Obvious" character throughout the United States for a year or so.

Comment: This is my wife's comment to me (since she refuses to buy into the *duh!* meme).

Answer (score 22):

If it's informal, [No shit, Sherlock](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_shit,_Sherlock) is an option.

> (vulgar, colloquial, sarcastic, somewhat derogatory) A riposte to someone who has just said something obvious
>
> - 1976, Emmett Grogan, Final score, page
>
>   "No shit, Sherlock. Take another look, see how they come to be bent."
> - 2006, Barry Morgan, Never Tell Them You're Dying, page 127:
>
>   My copilot uttered, "I think we are headed for the bridge." No shit, Sherlock.

Comment: It goes back farther than 1976--it was common when I was in high school in the early 1960s.

Comment: @StoneyB: And if you're in elementary school, the followup is "constipated, Watson?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I choose surlawda because he send it first.

Answer (score 20):

We often say *[duh!](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/duh)*

> (informal)
>   Used to comment on an action perceived as foolish or stupid, or a statement perceived as obvious:
>
> *I left the keys in the ignition—duh!*
>
> *Leopold correctly informs him that the opera is in Italian (duh!)*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: This has the disadvantage that it can be misunderstood as "D'oh!" - as in "Oh, of course, silly me, thanks for pointing that out".

Comment: @DewiMorgan Always a possibility, but in the Northeast US, we tend to draw out the *duh!*, almost a *du-uh!*, while while our *D'oh!* tends to be short and clipped. It's all in the inflection.

Comment: yeah, if you can *hear* it, then it works just fine - speech carries a whole lot more meaning than text. (Well, duh!)

Comment: The best in all history is: Duh Ashley, all wool comes from a cow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgOiM-oa2gA

Comment: I believe that this is one of the best answers here, and I feel that you've muddied the waters by including the "I left the keys in the ignition" example.  IMNSHO, foolish/stupid actions don't go with ***duh***; they go with ***d'oh!*** And yes, I see that you've linked to the Oxford Dictionaries, so I am saying that they don't know American English very well.

Answer (score 17):

You can also consider [you don't say](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+don't+say). Another  [link from wikitonary.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_don%27t_say)

> It means someone has just said something that everyone knows or is obvious >It is also used to express lack of surprise about what someone said in an unkind way

Comment: This can heavily depend on the tone of voice used.  A mild tone can indicate slight surprise; a disinterested/patronizing tone might be used when the speaker is disinterested but polite.  A sarcastic tone would fit the OP's question.

Comment: http://paulmarin.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/you-dont-say.jpg

Answer (score 10):

*[In other news] Water is wet.*
The first part is optional.

*The pope is catholic.*

Both are tautologies, and I couldn't find origins for the sayings, but they're pretty widespread and convey the same meaning as your original phrase.

Out of curiosity, where are you from? Spanish is my native language and I've never heard that expression.

Comment: Im from Venezuela.

Comment: ¡Saludos de México!  ñ__ñ

Comment: One usually sees the second as a question, used to parry an equally obvious question.  *"Is the stove hot?*" *"I dunno, is the Pope Catholic?*" also: "*Does a bear crap in the woods?*"

Comment: Agree with @Ketura. A variant on this is as follows: Q: "Will this take long?" A: "Does the Pope wear a funny hat and kiss runways?"

Answer (score 9):

Another common expression in English, said with a sarcastic tone, is

> Ya think?!

In other words, the subtext is "Duh! Everyone knows that," or "Well obviously . . .."

Answer (score 4):

"*Details at 11*" - as if it will be appearing in the late evening news broadcast (not).

This is a common Trope. [George Carlin used it](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FilmAtEleven).

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know. One thing to remember, though. If you keep posting a low-quality answer, you could be blocked from answering a question. It's up to you. Do you think I would care?

Comment: @Rathony OK, I added a link. Maybe the Juggernaut has already moved too far to rescind the wrath of con.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Pope Catholic?
Does a bear shit in the woods?

Comment: I always heard that one the other way around. Dumb Boy Scouts...

Comment: @nocomprende, so, Catholic bears?

Answer (score 1):

Another one you may consider using:

> Yes, and the sky is blue

Answer (score 1):

***tell me about it***

> *Slang.* What you are saying is obvious; so what else is new: *''Put the water on while I shower. I smell like a goat.'' ''Tell me about it''* (1980s+)
>
> [The Dictionary of American Slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tell-me-about-it)

[***color me surprised!***](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/color-me-surprised.2160729/?hl=fr)

> means you are not surprised or shocked at all and you are being ironic about it.

Answer (score 1):

One expression that may still have some resonance with English speakers, even though fewer and fewer people think of "breaking news" as something that is reported in print and published on a deadline, is "**Stop the presses!**" As the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_press) for this expression observes,

> **"Stop Press"** or **"Stop the Presses"** is a phrase stemming from the printed news media industry as an exclamation signifying the discovery of the need to change the content of an issue just before, or during its printing.
>
> Since this meant that the printing press literally had to be stopped or delayed and much of the existing copies of a publication which had already printed had to be discarded - which carried extreme cost, it is a phrase indicating the arrival of extremely significant news or the discovery of an extremely grave error. The phrase is common in an idiomatic context, referring to the discovery of significant information and is often used sarcastically.

As sarcastic remarks go, it's pretty mild, but it still gets the point across that something that one person considers noteworthy may not be news to someone (or anyone) else.

Answer (score 0):

***Queen Anne is dead*** -
a sarcastic response to someone who tells an old news.

"*Its so hot in India*"

-*Queen Anne is dead*!

This question has been asked before by a user. Below is the link-

[Where does the idiom "Queen Anne is dead!" come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/where-does-the-idiom-queen-anne-is-dead-come-from)

Comment: I like the concept of this, but I feel the need to point out that, as a native speaker of (American) English, I've never heard it in my life.

Comment: The origin of this phrase was asked by a user once, below is the link :

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/where-does-the-idiom-queen-anne-is-dead-come-from

Comment: @QualityTalk I think it would do good if you edited your answer to include the link in your comment.

Comment: The American equivalent of this might be "Generalissimo Francisco Franco is still dead."  From a recurring Saturday Night Live skit (TV show).

Comment: Well I dont know who are Queen Anne or Generalissimo Fracisco Franco... But the second one think I hear it before.

Answer (score 0):

> What else is new?

in a sarcastic tone indicates that the other person said something "not new".

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for something less slangy and more dignified, a simple, "Obviously", or, "Indubitably," may suffice.